# React Bootstrap - Cannot apply own styles to Modals

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a React App with React Bootstrap and am currently trying to make a modal with two content sections side by side (for Registration on the left and Login on the right). I am trying to add a style to the Modal, but no styles affect it (neither regular css nor react-jss). This works fine for Button, for example (with both regular css and react-jss). Why is that? I have currently added a div inside the Modal which has the style the modal should have, but it's less than ideal. Here is my current code:

```
function MyVerticallyCenteredModal(props: {show: boolean, onHide: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>)=>void}): JSX.Element {
    const modalSideBySide = {display: "flex", flexDirection: "row"};
    const useStyles = createUseStyles({modalSideBySide});
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Modal
            {...props}
            size="lg"
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            centered
            z-index={10}
        >
            <div className={classes.modalSideBySide}>
                <div>
                    <Modal.Header /*closeButton*/>
                        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                            Registration
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
                        <p>
                            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
                            dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac
                            consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
                        </p>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        {/*<Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>*/}
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                            Login
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
                        <p>
                            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
                            dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac
                            consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
                        </p>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        {/*<Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>*/}
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

I have copied the Modal from the React Bootstrap page and will be changing it, but first I want to fix the styling.

Edit: I couldn't upload the code on FiddleJs or CodePen.

```
function MyVerticallyCenteredModal(props) {
    const modalSideBySide = {display: "flex", flexDirection: "row"};
    const useStyles = createUseStyles({modalSideBySide});
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Modal
            {...props}
            size="lg"
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            centered
            z-index={10}
        >
            <div className={classes.modalSideBySide}>
                <div>
                    <Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                            Registration
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
                        <p>
                            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
                            dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac
                            consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
                        </p>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                            Login
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
                        <p>
                            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
                            dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac
                            consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
                        </p>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <MyVerticallyCenteredModal show={true}/>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This is my code simplified in the App.test.js file when I create a WebStorm project. When I have the className on the div, it works correctly, but when I add the className to the Modal and remove the unnecessary wrapping div the styles aren't added. Adding styles this way works on React Bootstrap Buttons, for example. The following is my index.js file (I haven't edited it except to remove the comment because StackOverflow didn't allow it):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or codepen, it will be easier to check it out.

Comment: I am currently not at my PC, but I will able to do that in about an hour.